# Game: Nine Heads and Tails

Tags: python, list, matrix, multidimensional-array

Description of Game:
Nine coins are placed in a 3x3 matrix with some face up and some face down. You can represent the state of the coins with the values 0(heads) and 1(tails).
##(Here are some examples: 000  101  110  101
010  001  100  110
000  100  001  100)##
Each state can also be represented using a binary number. (For example, the preceding matrices correspond to the numbers: 000010000   101001100   110100001   101110100).
There are a total of 512 possibilities. So, you can use the decimal numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., and 511 to represent all states of the matrix.

My goal is to write a program that prompts the user to enter a number between 0 and 511 and displays the corresponding 3x3 matrix with the characters H and T.
##(ex. "Enter a # between 0 and 511: " (7)   the user entered 7, which corresponds to 000000111. Since 0 stand for H and 1 for T, the output is:
HHH
HHH
TTT) ##

I'm finding this a bit complicated, so I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out with figuring out how to start this out or complete it. Any suggestions or tips are appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify the relation between a state and it's number? How 7 corresponds to 000000111 ?

Comment: The first step is to accept user input of a number between 0 and 511.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Unsel binary `111` is the same as decimal 7.

Comment: Unsel, I'm not exactly sure. The description I gave was everything I'm working with, so I'm not really sure how to clarify. It's a really confusing assignment.

Comment: @JohnGordon clarified it. Thanks :)

Comment: John, Ya, I get that part, but I'm not sure what I should be doing to get the 512 different possible matrices. Would I be using random at all?

Comment: No, you don't need random.  The user enters the state; you don't generate it randomly yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
val = int(input("Enter your value:"))
if val>=0 and val<=511:
    for indx,i in enumerate(bin(val)[2:].zfill(9)):
        if i=='0':
            print("H",end=" ")
        else:
            print("T",end=" ")
        if indx %3==2:
            print(" ",end="")
    print()
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Break apart the problem;
You need to (in my opinion) break each step into its most basic form.

Ie.

1. Take input (presumably as an int between 0-511, or alternatively as a binary string).
2. Convert to binary string (if given number).
3. Build 3x3 array on this basis.

Obviously there is more to do, but start by thinking about each step, and how you need to solve that step. Best advice I can give.